# RuntimeWarning: couroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

Command I'm having trouble with:

```
@bot.command()
async def auction(ctx, starting, items, items2):
    price = starting

    embed1=discord.Embed(title=f'**__Auction Starting!__**', description=f'**{ctx.author}** is starting an auction for **{items} {items2}**.\nThe starting price is **⏣ {starting}**.', color=discord.Color.gold())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
    embed2=discord.Embed(title=f'**__Current Price__**', description=f'The price is currently:\n**⏣ {price}**.', color=discord.Color.gold())
    message1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed2)

    end = False
    while not end:
      try:
        user = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=3600)
        bid = int(user.content)
        if int(bid) > 0:
          price += f"{bid}"
          await message1.edit(embed=embed2)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        end = True
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeWarning: couroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited.
  super().dispatch(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback.
```

Here is the full code if needed:
https://mystb.in/MechanicsRoommatePhone.python

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely in the `check()` function (which you are not showing here).

Make sure to define your `check()` function as a synchronous function, not `async`!

`def check(m):`

In the case that you really need `check()` to be an asynchronous function you will need to use something like [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) (in Python >=3.7) or [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) (in Python >=3.4.2) or [`asyncio.ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) (in Python >=3.4.4).

Be aware that `asyncio.create_task()` (and the other functions) will return straight away, and will not wait for the task to be finished. The task will be *scheduled* to run after a one or more `await`s elsewhere.